# Get absolute path of the file in vc++/visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2008, mfc

I am new to VC++ programming. I am developing a program where in I have to get absolute path of a *.bmp file from all the folders in a directory dynamically. I am able to navigate to every folder in the directory dynamically but not able to get absolute path of the files.
I am not able to use "GetFullPathName", I am not sure if this will solve the purpose.
Please help.

Comment: It is a chicken-and-egg question.  You'd need to full path of the directory first.  Getting the full path of the file is then simple, you just append its name to the directory path name with an extra backslash.  You did not at all describe how you know where to look.

Comment: Explain more about the "not able to use `GetFullPathName`". That is where the problem lies, obviously!

Comment: Show us an example of what you want exactly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [CFileFind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f33e1618%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to locate the files, you should be able to use CFileFind::GetFilePath () to get the complete path.